# Hard time debugging Local Variable in XCode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, macos, gcc

I'm having a hard-time debugging a local variable.  I'm running `gcc 4.2`, `XCode 3.2.4`, base SDK `Mac OS 10.5`, and `Objective-C++` in Debug-Mode.

Here's the issue.  I'm working on trying to understand some code and it goes like this:

```
#define MAX4D 500

...

NSMutableArray *viewerPix[ MAX4D ];
```

When I hover over it during debug (pause on the line before and after)  I get this

```
Unable to access variable "viewerPix"
Unable to access variable "viewerPix"
Unable to access variable "viewerPix"
...
```

repeated until I kill the application.  What would cause this?  I've tried setting it to a lower number... but to no avail.  Even after I actually set the C-Array:

```
viewerPix[0] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

I still get the same repeated error message.

However, if I don't mouse-over the value (or debug) it "appears" to run fine, even doing stuff like:

```
[viewerPix[0] addObject: dcmPix];
if( [viewerPix[0] count] != [loadList count])...
```

but if I debug after those steps, it crashes just like before.  Here are my build settings:

STRIPFLAGS =
ALTERNATE_GROUP = $(INSTALL_GROUP)
ALTERNATE_OWNER = $(INSTALL_OWNER)
ALTERNATE_MODE = $(INSTALL_MODE_FLAG)
ALTERNATE_PERMISSIONS_FILES =
DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION = NO
DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING = NO
INSTALL_GROUP = $(GROUP)
INSTALL_OWNER = $(USER)
INSTALL_MODE_FLAG = u+w,go-w,a+rX
DSTROOT = /tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME).dst
INSTALL_PATH = $(HOME)/Applications
SKIP_INSTALL = NO
COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO
STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT =
STRIP_STYLE = debugging
SEPARATE_STRIP = NO

GCC_FAST_OBJC_DISPATCH = YES
GCC_AUTO_VECTORIZATION = NO
GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS = YES
GCC_ENABLE_SSE3_EXTENSIONS = NO
GCC_ENABLE_SSE41_EXTENSIONS = NO
GCC_ENABLE_SSE42_EXTENSIONS = NO
GCC_ENABLE_SUPPLEMENTAL_SSE3_INSTRUCTIONS = NO
GCC_STRICT_ALIASING = NO
GCC_FEEDBACK_DIRECTED_OPTIMIZATION = Off
GCC_ENABLE_FIX_AND_CONTINUE = NO
GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = YES
GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO
GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES = NO
GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES
GCC_MODEL_TUNING = G5
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO
GCC_ENABLE_KERNEL_DEVELOPMENT = NO
GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = default
GCC_REUSE_STRINGS = YES
GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = NO
GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC = unsupported
GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0
GCC_FAST_MATH = NO
GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION = YES
GCC_THREADSAFE_STATICS = YES
GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO
GCC_UNROLL_LOOPS = NO
GCC_MODEL_PPC64 = NO

I don't know what else to say.  Let me know what more information is needed, because I'm at a loss.  There's also no 'build' tab when I get-info on the `.mm` file.  Just General, Target, Comments (some helps I checked said to remove file-specific tags).

Should I initialize that c-array to `nil`?  I can't just do.. `array[500] = {nil};` right?  that's C#?

I was using LLVM and Clang 1.5, but I switched to GCC 4.2 since I wasn't getting *any* local symbols.  Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the optimizer is on, that can effectively eliminate local variables.

However, why a C array of mutable ObjC arrays?  That seems odd.

Comment: yes, yes it is.  I don't have time to refactor all of [OsiriX](http://www.osirix-viewer.com)'s code, so I'm doing the best I can.  It's a port from OS9 C program.

Answer (score 0):

check Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run xxx,  Build Configuration  is Debug,   if that is Release happened you see.